# how to render div with template using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, gsp

I'm trying to render a div with a template in ajax. I'm using .html() function for setting the template data in div. But when I do so, it hides scroll bar of page and even the page doesn't scroll.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/method/action',
    data: $("#my_form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){

    $("#replacableDiv").html('');
    $("#companyModal").modal('hide');
    $(".modal-backdrop").hide();
    $("#replacableDiv").html(data);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Could you make jsFiddle.net?

Comment: You append method instead

Comment: Without showing the actual HTML (in the page and returned in `data`) this cannot be solved except by guesses but it is probably a styling issue. Simplest way to test is style the `#replacableDiv` to have a fixed height and width (and also `overflow: auto` to allow it to scroll the content).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#replacableDiv').append(data);
```